# Using MAPI to change attachment filename

Tags: outlook, mapi

Using COM and MAPI, we are trying to rename an attachment in an MSG file.  I've got everything working (we get the IAttach interface, then use GetProps and SetProps), but I'm nervous about making sure that we change all the properties we need to.

Does anyone know if the following is sufficient?

Check and if present, change value of:

- PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION_W
- PR_ATTACH_FILENAME_W
- PR_ATTACH_LONG_FILENAME_W
- PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W

Also, will setting the _W values automagically set the _A values?  I think yes, but can't find and reference documentation that says one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSG files do not automatically update the other flavor of a property - if you set PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION_W, PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION_A will *not* be automatically created/updated. You can check if a particular property exists, then update it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm finding that setting PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION to a unicode string does indeed also set the PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION_W value.  I'd guess that setting it to a non-unicode value would also set the PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION_A value.  So I'm using the undecorated property IDs, then checking the return value type and using that to determine what type of value I set when I change the property.

Comment: Can you see both properties in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) if you click OpenIMsgOnIStg? Note that if you double on an MSG file and then click on the IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, you will be looking on a copy of the MSG file created in one of the Outlook folders, not on the original MSG file.

Comment: I'm using MfcMapi to look at things (hacked the code to get it to display the attachment properties) - it shows the _W version of the property (PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION_W) with an additional column listing the applicable aliases (which includes the non-type-decorated property ID - PR_ATTACH_EXTENSION).  I'll take a look with OutlookSpy when I'm back in the office.

Comment: OK - I checked using OutlookSpy, and it only shows the _W property.  But I'm able to set the non _W property just fine.  For example, I obtain the properties table for the attachment, get the property for PR_ATTACH_FILENAME, query and see that it's type is PT_UNICODE, then I set the lpszW value.  If the type is PT_STRING8, then I set the lpszA value.  I then call SetProps.  The result has the PR_ATTACHFILENAME_W value being set.

Comment: PS - I really like OutlookSpy - I learned a lot by hacking the MfcMapi code, but your tool is really nice for troubleshooting and poking around. Well done, sir!

Comment: That should work for the Outlook version of MAPI. I remember running into _W vs _A problems for the MSG files when the standalone (Exchange) version of MAPI is used...